# Lot of duplicate tweets in the output file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am taking twitter tweets through kafka and doing computation in the storm topology and saving it in the hdfs. I'm getting lot of duplicates in the file can any one tell how I can do it without duplicates

Comment: Check if it is there before saving? This is very easy, what's the problem?

Comment: You describe your problem very generally, and there could be numerous problems as to why you have duplicates. You need to be more specific in your question if you want a better answer.

Comment: Do you have fault-tolerance enabled and have faulty Spouts or bolts?

Comment: I am taking tweets as input... Cleaning the tweet text...and sending cleaned tweet text, tweet date, image URL , tweet Id and user I'd from twitter json and storing these value in an avro format.. When I see the output of avro files .. It showing duplicates of tweetId and user I'd s in the file that means iam receiving each tweet multiple times